# Error when adding include folder cmake

Tags: qt, cmake, header-files, dependency-management, include-path

I am creating new project using cmake to configure it. That project has dependency of library lib1, for example which is compiled separately.

Problem starts when I add include folder of the lib1 like this:

```
include_directories (../lib1/include)
```

When I launch make command it complains saying that

> fatal error: 'QSharedData' file not found
>
> #include < QSharedData >

QSharedData is included in one of the .h of lib1.

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is QSharedData a data structure that is defined in a header file? The `include` statement should refer to the header file and not its contents, i.e. something like `#include "../../lib1/headers.h"` or `#include <headers.h>`.

Comment: So you need to include directory which contains `QSharedData` header. The header is part of QT library. I suggest you to read documentation for the project you use; it should describe how to use it properly.

Comment: QSharedData is header file defined in framework Qt. It does exist.
Actually when I compile my lib it uses that header file. My question is if I need to add the path to it in my project although I am not using it directly

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely follow Qt's cmake instructions (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/cmake-manual.html) and use their cmake package, i.e.

```
find_package(Qt5Core)
...
```

The Qt cmake package takes care of determining and setting the needed include directories, etc.